# GCM server side code in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried the code for GCM given [here](http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html#comment-form)

Using this I am able to get the registration id for my application (I checked on the device and found it got printed onto the `TextView` that I set).

But now how can I check for the receiving of messages (push notifications) from the server.
Actually how to connect my code to the server?

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda vague. So you haven't set anything up on your server? First you need to set up the server. You just make a regular http call using the specifications found [GCM Server](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#server)

This is the server section but you might want to read the whole document to get the full picture